# QRegularExpressionMatch memory consumption

Tags: c++, qt

here is part of my code:

```
    int Parser::SomeFunction(const QString &line, int start, int& fieldStart, int& fieldLength ) const
{
    int end;
......
    if (0 == m_pRegExp)
    {
......
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef KNOWN_PATTERN
        end = 19;
#else

        QRegularExpressionMatch match = m_pRegExp->match(line,  start);
        if (!match.hasMatch())
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // currently we are requiring match to be found exactly at the position 'start'
        if (match.capturedStart() != start)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        end = match.capturedEnd();
#endif
    }
.....
}
```

The program loads a text file and parses its lines one by one. The whole purpose of code in ‘else’ scope is to calculate where a field ends (integer ‘end’) in the next line passed to the function. When I compile with KNOWN_PATTERN #defined and load some test file, for which I know ‘end’ should become 19, my program consumes about 400 MB less memory than when compiled without KNOWN_PATTERN #defined. 400 MB is what all lines of my test file occupy in the memory (I can can calculate it based of file size and also I watched memory consumption when file was loaded and before parsing started).
So it seems to me that QRegularExpressionMatch creates a copies of each line and does not release it.
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Task Manager and similar are very blunt tools for observing memory allocation by the C++ runtime.

In particular, the runtime doesn't necessarily release deallocated memory back to the OS, as OS memory allocation is relatively slow on many platforms, but holds on to it for itself.

Comment: Thank you molbdnilo for your answer. If OS defers actual memory deallocation than I would expect it to re-use it upon new allocation requests. But my 32-bit program reaches its 2Gb limit on Windows and crashes when I load 800MB file - just because these 800MB are duplicated by temps like those in the code I shown and not freed nor reused? Second, can you suggest a better tools to monitor actual memory usage in Windows? Thanks

Comment: @mvidelgauz It should reuse when it needs to, so that's strange. But do you really need to load the entire 800 MB at once? It's not the most scalable idea in the world.

Comment: It doesn't return as I mentioned and yes I know it is generally not good idea to load entire 800 MB, but for the specific program that's the best way to achieve goals - the software is log4j file viewer with multiple views/filters/search results and fast browsing back and forward in each (individually filtered) view